# Get specific chars from a string in python

Tags: python

I want to make a new string from an internal part of an old string, and when I know the length of the string I know I can do this:

```
newString = oldString[6:145]
```

This exludes the first and last chars from the old string when writing the newString. But is there a way to do this if i dont know the length of the string, like:

```
newString = oldString[6:len(oldString)-6]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
newString = oldString[6:-6]
```